# Marking services for secure handling; Annotation or inheritance?

Tags: security, web-services, aspect-oriented, inheritance

We have a lot of services, some that demand some security, some that don't.
We want an easy way of telling, in code, if a service will be secure or not.

What would be the better way: Annotation or inheritance?

```
public class SomeServiceImplementation : BaseSecureService, ISomeService
```

or

```
[SecureService]
public class SomeServiceImplementaion : ISomeService
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use annotations**

Security is generally considered a cross-cutting concern so an inheritance path is generally unsuitable for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

As you said *marking services.* in the question the answer is annotations / attributes.

[C# attributes can be placed on entities in your source code to specify additional information.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288059%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

This seems to fit what you need.

If each entity were required to provide certain functions to participate in the security then it would be best to use an interface.